# How to disable proximity sensor programmatically

Tags: android

I am making a screen lock app. In this app when user listen call then screen turn off and screen lock activate due to proximity sensor.

I have done many tries with different angles but failed.

Now I want to disable proximity sensor with the help of code in my app.

Comment: @ Khilafat E Rashida : Add what you have tried so far like code sample..!!